# Loop output is not what I desired

Tags: java

I am trying to complete my for loop for the following output;

desired output: [1  4  9  16  25  36  49  64  81  100]

Code:

```
for(int i = 1; i<=100; i = i + 2) 
    {
        int sum = i;
        i = sum + 1;

        System.out.print(i + " ");  
    }
```

Please help!

Comment: Since this seems like homework, I will give you a hint. The expected output seems like a sequence of perfect squares. Do you really need to iterate till 100? Do you need to add or ___?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want to achieve in fact just showing the square of each number from one to ten so just do that

```
System.out.print("[");
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++){
        System.out.print(" "+i*i+" ");
}
System.out.print("]");
```

Disclaimer: code written on the phone so please forgive formatting

Comment: Killing time, aren't we?

Comment: Does it really matter? I mean OP's interest was more on the numbers than the spaces anyway. Not sure this matters in the end. Pretty sure you're just joking though

Comment: None of this matters, it is a silly question and what can you expect from anybody seeing this? I give up.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this:

```
System.out.print("[");
for(int i = 1; i<=10; i++) 
{
    System.out.print((i*i));
    if(i!=10) System.out.print(" ");
}
System.out.print("]");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 1; i<=10; i++) 
{
    System.out.print((i * i) + " ");  
}
```

Comment: This same answer was given here earlier

Comment: But in fact none of the answers outputs the square brackets... which are present in the desired output :)